# How can I change an object field in a list and return the list with the changed object?

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

I have a data class Post:

```
data class Post(
    val id: Long,
    val author: String,
    val content: String,
    val published: String,
    var likedByMe: Boolean,
    var likes: Int = 0
)
```

And here is the list of objects of this class:

```
val post1 = Post(id = 1, "First", "Content", "0", false, 0)
val post2 = Post(id = 2, "Second", "Interesting", "0", false, 0)
val post3 = Post(id = 3, "Third", "Nothing", "0", false, 0)

val postsList = mutableListOf<Post>(post1, post2, post3)
```

I need to increment the number of likes for the first post and return the updated list (for example, print it). How can I do this, can you tell me please?

P.S. I think that it can be somehow implemented with a chain of extension-functions, like filter, map, etc., but I don't understand how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To mutate *likes* of *post1*:

```
postsList[0].likes += 1
```

To mutate *likes* of *post1* and return a new list:

```
val newList = postsList
  .mapIndexed { index, post ->
    if (index == 0) ++post.likes
    post                                              // return mutated post1
  }
```

To clone *post1* and then mutate its *likes* (thereby leaving *post1* unchanged), and return a new list:

```
val newList = postsList
  .mapIndexed { index, post ->
    if (index == 0) post.copy(likes = post.likes + 1) // return mutated clone
    else post                                         // return non-mutated posts
  }
```

Note that each data class has an automatically created *copy()* function, which creates a clone and can take any of the properties as argument(s) and assigns new values to these properties.

Corrections made according to first comment by @Joffrey.

Comment: In the last example, `post.likes++` should be `post.like + 1` if you don't want to mutate the original post. Also, `post.likes++` actually evaluates to the previous value, which is not what you want here. So if you want to mutate the original AND return the value + 1, it should be `++post.likes`.

Comment: @Joffrey: Thank you very much. Made the changes.

Comment: @Joffrey: I'm suddenly not sure if the second example really needs the prefix version, as post.likes++ would give the same result as ++post.likes, wouldn't it? The last line with _post_ is relevant for the new list.

Comment: Indeed in the second example it doesn't matter because the value of the increment expression is not used

Comment: Thank you, guys!
lukas.j - The second option using "mapindexed" is exactly what I need!
@Joffrey - Good point about ++post.likes. I've been caught with that before)

Comment: @KurtcaBain note that the second example should almost never be what you need. Mutating the original list + returning a new list almost never makes sense. Please double check whether you really need to mutate the item from the original list, and if you really need to create a new list identical to the initial one (the mutation will be in both lists if you use that second snippet)